# An $n\times n$ matrix, $n\ge 2$ with characteristic polynomial $x^{n-2}(x^2-1)$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank, characteristic-polynomial, cayley-hamilton

> $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, $n\ge 2$ with characteristic polynomial $x^{n-2}(x^2-1)$. Then, which of the following is true?
>
> 1. $A^n=A^{n-2}$
> 2. rank of $A$ is $2$
> 3. rank of $A$ is atleast $2$
> 4. there are non-zero vectors $x$ and $y$ such that $A(x+y)=x-y$

Using Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, (1) is true. But, I can't figure out whether the other options are true or not.

I guess, (3) is also true because of the diagonal matrix
$$A=D\left(\underbrace{0,0,\dots ,0}_{n-2 \text{  times}}, -1,1\right)$$
for even $n$ as in this case
$$A-xI=D\left(\underbrace{-x,-x,\dots ,-x}_{n-2 \text{  times}}, -x-1,1-x\right)$$
but of course, that is not a proof.

Comment: Hint for 3 and 4: $1$ and $-1$ are eigenvalues. For 2 find a counterexample. Think of a Jordan matrix with n=4.

Comment: Where is this exercise from?